# if (static_cast<bool>(x)) vs if (x)

Tags: c++, casting, conditional-statements, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

I have a coworker who routinely does an explicit cast to bool in conditionals, as in:

```
SomeType *ptr = /* some value */;
if (static_cast<bool>(ptr)) {
    // do something
}
```

But I haven't been able to find a good reason for such verbosity. Any ideas?

Edit: The coworker says it’s about clarity and being explicit, but I don’t find this explanation to be very compelling. I brought the question here to see if other C++ experts recommend this, and if so, perhaps a more compelling argument would emerge.

Comment: Some coding guidelines may forbid using implicit conversions in conditionals. However, `if (ptr != nullptr)` is usually preferred in such cases.

Comment: The obvious answer to me is to take a minute to ask your coworker.

Comment: @chris: Yes, that’s a good place to start, and in fact, I did. Edited question to include the details. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Broadly speaking, there is no objectively good reason to do this. For pointers, it's actually negatively useful. Pointer conversion to `bool` is a well-defined operation in C++ and has been since the days of C (and likely before). It's a basic idiom that every C++ programmer *needs to learn*. Explicitly doing the conversion sends the message that an explicit conversion is somehow different from the implicit contextual conversion, which it is not.

Also, a user who doesn't know what `if(ptr)` does probably also doesn't know what converting a pointer to `bool` will do at all. So `if(static_cast<bool>(ptr))` can't even be defended as being more clear; `if(ptr != nullptr)` is far more clear as to what's going on to a neophyte.

Comment: `if(ptr != nullptr)` in this case.  `if (ptr)` idiom is so... so... idiomatic for C and for C++.  Even the `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` support the idiom.

Comment: @Eljay: It's an evil idiom, which breaks the [principle of least astonishment](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment) for people who don't already know it. Used `if (ptr != nullptr)` like a boss. +1 on Nicol's answer.

Answer (score 2):

`if (static_cast<bool>(ptr))` is completely equivalent to `if (ptr)`.

Maybe your colleague thinks using `static_cast` adds some clarity to the code.

Comment: Not sure what clarity it adds. If you wanted to make the condition clearer, you would write `if(ptr != nullptr)`.

Comment: @uneven_mark I'm not sure either. I myself wouldn't use a `static_cast` here.

Comment: Although `if(ptr)` is a very old idiom (one that I'm using myself every day!) reading the standard, I am now not really sure about that. 7.14 says "A prvalue of [...], pointer, or [...] can be converted to a prvalue of type bool". Now, `ptr` here isn't a prvalue, methinks. It doesn't compute the value of an operator, nor does it initialize a bitfield or object. So, in the strictest sense... hmm... if one wrote `if(ptr != nullptr)` then it sure _would_ compute the value of an operator, so that'd be legitimate.

Comment: @Damon When citing the standard, use the stable section names, e.g. here you cite [conv.bool]. The numeric section counters often change between the standard versions/drafts.

Comment: @Damon The condition is *contexually converted to bool*, which also incurs *lvalue-to-rvalue* conversion. The boolean conversion can happen after that.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, you've been able to specify an `explicit bool` conversion, which is only triggered when using in situations such as `if (myObj) { … }` but not in situations like `bool b = myObj;`. The statements are equivalent, but your co-worker may have been trying to provide the "explicit" nature of the conversion in syntax only. To summarise, you don't need the `static_cast<bool>(myObj)`, and following C++11, you've got type-safety provided.